# При перезапуске приложения не сохраняются данные

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка

У меня 3 класса: MainActivity.java, StartGame.java и EndGame.java. При запуске открывается MainActivity.java, нажимаем кнопку "Начать" и переходим в StartGame.java. В StartGame.java есть таймер обратного отсчёта. По истечению времени работы таймера открывается EndGame.java. При выходе из приложения, перезапуске значение таймера сбрасывается. То есть при сворачивании всё нормально, но при выходе опять открывается MainActivity, потом StartGame, но таймер начинает отсчёт заново. Как это исправить?

Код:

```
public class StartGame extends AppCompatActivity {
long duration = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24);
long endOfTask = System.currentTimeMillis() + duration;
final String TAG = "STATE";
static SharedPreferences save;
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "save";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_TODO = "todo";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER = "chronometer";
Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.start_game);
context = this;

//Array
String[] tasks = {"..."};
// Calculate how many words are in the array
int tasksLength = tasks.length;
//Generate random
int rand = (int) (Math.random() * tasksLength);

//Set task
String task = tasks[rand] + " ";
TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
todo.setText(task);
 saveText();

      //Button Back START
Window w = getWindow();
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
Button buttonBack = findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);

buttonBack.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartGame.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } saveText();
});
// Button Back END

}


 //System button Back START
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
    super.onBackPressed();

    try {
        saveText();
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartGame.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    saveText();
}
//System button Back END

void saveText () {
  TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
  SharedPreferences save = StartGame.this.getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = save.edit();
  editor.putLong(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, endOfTask);
  editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_TODO, todo.getText().toString());
  editor.apply();
  }

   void loadText () {
    TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
    TextView chronometer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    SharedPreferences save = StartGame.this.getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
    todo.setText(save.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_TODO, todo.getText().toString()));
    //long finalTime = (save.getLong(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, Long.valueOf(endOfTask)) - System.currentTimeMillis());
     long finalTime = save.getLong(APP_PREFERENCES_CHRONOMETER, endOfTask);
    long finalLong = finalTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer( finalLong, 1000) {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            String duration = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d : %02d : %02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(l)), (l / 1000) % 60);
            chronometer.setText(duration);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartGame.this, EndGame.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }; timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
saveText();
Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
}

 @Override
 protected void onStop() {
saveText();
super.onStop();
Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
loadText();
Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
saveText();
Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

 @Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
loadText();
Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
super.onRestart();
loadText();
Log.d(TAG, "onRestart");
 }

    @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
outState.putLong("chronometer", endOfTask);
outState.putString("todo", todo.getText().toString());
saveText();
     Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");

 }

  @Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
TextView todo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.todo);
SharedPreferences save = StartGame.this.getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
loadText();
todo.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("todo"));
Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
  }

   }
```

Использовать loadText()  в onCreate() не получится, потому что при первом запуске тогда значения loadText() будут равны нулю. Как решить эту проблему, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Проблема может быть в передаче SharedPreferences разных активити

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте параметры по умолчанию и в onCreate вызывайте либо их, либо loadText при наличии в нем данных.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Только не совсем понял, что Вы имеете в виду. Вы бы не могли уточнить что значит по умолчанию?

Comment: Запиши в loadText значение до компиляции и всегда вызывай оттуда, а перед переходом в EndGame записывай какое значение нужно загрузить при следующем запуске.

Comment: Если saveText() сохраняет в место, из которого после запуска нельзя достать данные, тогда, нужно сохранить значение таймера в файл или sqlite базу.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]